# How to run .NET Core project with PVS-Studio without Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, pvs-studio

I have the [free license](https://www.viva64.com/en/b/0600/) for **PVS-Studio** and I installed the program to Windows 10 computer without issues. I gave the registration info via **Standalone.exe** and registration went OK. This computer doesn't not have Visual Studio installed (only Dotnet core SDK and Visual Studio Code)

When I try to run dotnet core project with it

> PVS-Studio_Cmd.exe -t C:\Users\someuser\projects\myproject.csproj

I get following error

> PVS-Studio Command Line Analyzer 7.0.29703.1460
>   Copyright (c) 2008-2019 OOO "Program Verification Systems"
>   Using default settings file: C:\Users\someuser\AppData\Roaming\PVS-Studio\Settings.xml
>   Exception message:
>   The imported project "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\15.0\Microsoft.Common.props" was not found. Also, tried to find "\15.0\Microsoft.Common.props" in the fallback search path(s) for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) - "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild" . These search paths are defined in "c:\Program Files (x86)\PVS-Studio\PVS-Studio_Cmd.exe.Config". Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk in one of the search paths.  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.props

So how should I fix the problem?

The project can be correctly build with **dotnet build** command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue will be resolved in the upcoming PVS-Studio version 7.02 release, which will also add support for Visual Studio 2019. .NET Core projects can now be analyzed without the need to install Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes, it works with latest release. `PVS-Studio_Cmd.exe -t my_project.csproj` generates .plog file